# Orthogonal projection of continuous function in $L^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be some measure space, say a probability space for simplicity, and let $P:L^2(X,\mu) \to V$ be an orthogonal projection onto some closed subspace $V$, which contains the constants. If $f\in L^2(X,\mu)$ is continuous, do we know that $P(f)$ is also continuous?

I haven't seen this asked or mentioned somewhere and it doesn't seem like the properties of orthogonal projections would guarantee that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to construct a simple counterexample: take $L^2[0,1]$ with Lebesgue and let $V=\text {span}\{ 1,g\}$, where $g$ is a discontinuous function of your choice. Now, take any continuous function $f$ with zero average, but with $\int_0^1 fg\ne 0$.